# Find value of more than one variable - JS

Tags: javascript, loops

I have the following JavaScript source :

```
var Fname = document.getElementById("FirstName").value;
var Lname = document.getElementById("LastName").value;
var email = document.getElementById("Email").value;
var password = document.getElementById("Pass").value;
var reapeat = document.getElementById("Repeat").value;
var area = document.getElementById("selectArea").value;
```

Is there any easy way to check **for each variable** if it's empty (`Fname == ""`)? If yes, how should I do it? If no, what is the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this with a loop you need the fields or values in a structure that is loopable, e.g., an array:

```
var fields = ["FirstName", "LastName", "Email", "Pass", "Repeat", "selectArea"];

for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById(fields[i]).value === "") {
        alert("Please fill in all fields.");
        break; // or do whatever you like here.
    }
 }
```

Or you could give the elements a common class in your markup, like:

```
<input class="noblank" ...>
```

and then:

```
var fields = document.getElementsByClassName("noblank");
for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    if (fields[i].value === "") {
        alert("Please fill in all fields.");
        break; // or do whatever you like here.
    }
 }
```

The class-based approach is a bit nicer because if you add more compulsory fields in your html you don't have to update the JS at all.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use `Object` as a dictionary:

```
var obj = {
    Fname: document.getElementById("FirstName").value,
    Lname: document.getElementById("LastName").value,
    email: document.getElementById("Email").value,
    password: document.getElementById("Pass").value,
    reapeat: document.getElementById("Repeat").value,
    area: document.getElementById("selectArea").value
};
for (var key in obj) {
   if (obj[key]) { //or any other condition
      //do stuff
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`ECMA 5` version

```
var fields = ["FirstName", "LastName", "Email", "Pass", "Repeat", "selectArea"];

fields.some(function(value) {
    if (this.getElementById(value).value === "") {
        alert("Please fill in the blanks.");
        return true;
    }
}, document);
```

Or you could build another object which represents which ones were missing,

```
var fields = ["FirstName", "LastName", "Email", "Pass", "Repeat", "selectArea"];
var errors = {};

fields.forEach(function(value) {
    if (this.getElementById(value).value === "") {
        errors[value] = "Please fill in the blanks.";
    }
}, document);
```

This way you would have access to the `error` object.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to validate a form. You could make the task easier by using a library, like jQuery.

But if you want to do it in pure JS, you could do something simple like this:

```
function formNotEmpty() {
    var i, fields = ['FirstName', 'LastName', ... ];

    for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i += 1) {
        if (fields[i] === '' || fields === null) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You could make it as complex as you would like, query the DOM to get the fields dynamically so you don't need to define the fields array etc.

Note that I use a triple equals operator (===) instead of a double (==), read why (and a lot more tips) about that here http://www.jslint.com/lint.html

Comment: That function only tests the values of the strings in the array, not the values of the fields. What's the _null_ check for?